# iPhone Simulator versions below 6.0 no longer appear in Xcode 4.5 scheme drop down

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator

Newbie questions. While learning Objective-C using Xcode 4.5.3 and the book Programming In Objective-C 4th edition, I have reached the final chapter in which two iPhone apps are built. Before building the apps I downloaded iOS simulators 4.1, 5.0 and 5.1.

When I built the first simple iphone app I was able to select iphone 5.0 simulator in the scheme. When I built the second, more complex app I tried to change the scheme which had defaulted to iPhone 6.0 simulator back to iphone 5.0 simulator only to find that that no simulator below 6.0 is available in the drop down any longer.

Having shrugged my shoulders and allowed the launch of my app in the 6.0 simulator I found that one row of the buttons do not display properly in the simulator. This row appears on top of another row with their labels blank or '-'. The xib for this project was created entirely visually according to the book's instructions as I do not yet know how to programatically code the user interface.

I have two questions:

1. How do I test this app in the iPhone 5 simulator if this scheme is no longer available in the scheme menu;
2. Why does the iphone 6.0 simulator fail to resemble the xib?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, be sure that you have the Simulator downloaded for 5.0 and 5.1, for this, go to "Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads", and you will see it there.

If you have them, the next step is to check that your project is deployed in those versions. For this, go to your project properties (click in the project in the project navigator) and check the Property "iOS Deployment Target" in the Info tab.

Next step, in the same screen click in your target and check the tab "Build Settings", and check the property "Base SDK" to see which iOS version you have there.

Let me know how it goes!

Comment: Yes I have downloaded the 5.0 and 5.1 simulators. I could only find IOS deployment target under Build Settings and not under Info. I was able to change IOS deployment target under builod settings to 5.0. I found Base SDK, but there were no IOS options below 6.0 here. However I was able to change the scheme to iphone 5.0 simulator after making the change to  the ios deployment target setting. But when I ran it it crashed with the following error "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'Could not instantiate class named NSLayoutConstraint'".

Comment: I fixed the crash by unticking 'Use Autolayout' under 'Interface Builder Document' under 'File Inspector' in the right hand column for the xib. Thanks for your answer Antonio MG. The display issues are fixed running the iphone 5.0 simulator.

Answer (score 0):

This is in answer to my second question:
Why does the iphone 6.0 simulator fail to resemble the xib?

Autolayout. Once this option is unticked, display is as expected.