# Xcode / Simulator iPhone messes up display

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

[image]

As you can see, the simulator misses text on some buttons.  I also saw this same behavior following along on the TapCounter demo off of YouTube.

Another issue (not shown in the screenshot) is that if you press on any key on TapCounter, NSString stringWithFormat (see below)

```
- (IBAction)add {
       count++;
       number.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", count];
   }
```

The act of executing the stringWithFormat line nukes the formatting on the label and reverts it to default value.

I did make sure that the simulator size and development size are identical, as you canm see.

Comment: I am seeing the same, running latest Xcode, iOS 6 simulation. If I find the answer, will post it here. Smells like a bug in Xcode or the simulator though.

Comment: I so totally agree Tony.  My vote is that Apple has a bug in this version of their toolchain, just I wonder why nobody else notices it.  Maybe others use an older version or the toolchain is OS version dependent.  Interestingly enough, clicking on Apple logo | Software Update yields no updates, but then maybe unlike Microsoft, software updates only reflect the OS, not other Apple products like their toolchain.  if I have an older version, quite literally the new version just, just, just came out.  Anyways, my vote is a bug.

Comment: See my comment below Tony.  Missing button text is the result of the checked "Use Autolayout".  That leaves the disappearing format on labels in response to stringWithFormat.

Answer (score 0):

This question appears a few times on this site. The answer at [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13452566) worked for me, once I was able to interpret the instructions. Including getting the crash and fixing it.

Later: it appears that the fix of turning off auto-layout is enough to get the 6.0 simulator working - you might like to try this first to see if all the other stuff is actually necessary...

Comment: The only thing that I was not able to verify/test is the "Use Autolayout" comment.  I have no clue where that is.  As to the rest, I have XCode 4.5.2 (evidently in the last few days Apple released 4.5.3, as I downloaded everything a few days ago) and the 6.0 Simulator suite.  The project targets 6.0 and the simulator is 6.0.  Everything checks out, just the issue.

Comment: Okay, I found the "Use Autolayout".  The comment in the other post ommitted a key point.  You have to click on "MainStorybord_iPhone.Storyboard".  Then you will see "Interface Builder Document". As to the "File Inspector", the File Inspector area is not the most obvious, even though it is.  Anyways, unchecking the Use Autolayout fixes the missing text on the button, but DOES NOT fix the resetting of the formatting on the label when I use the NSString::stringWithFormat method, so one out of two so far.  Like I said, bug.  Autolayout should not cause that behavior.

Comment: I think you'll often find statements like "uncheck the use autolayout option", without much clue as to where to find it. The time spent looking for it should be considered as familiarisation with the tools!